# PayPal Manually Redirect to Order Confirmation Page

Tags: paypal

I'm aware on how to enable/disable PayPal's Auto Return feature. What I'd like to do is disable the Auto Return but still provide a button/link for the user to manually return to an order confirmation page on my site? Is this possible? Also, PDT requires Auto Return to be enabled, so I'm assuming that PDT will not work anymore. Is this true?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

If you disable Auto-Return the user will still see a little link that says "Return to Merchant" but it would show your company name in place the word Merchant.

I haven't tested it specifically, but according to the documentation you are correct that without Auto-Return enabled PDT will not send data to the return URL.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing a link/button on the confirmation page  ![Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/paypalhf.jpg/).

Comment: Are you using Payments Standard or Adaptive Payments, or what..??

Comment: Needed to turn off Auto-Return and specify a return url in form. <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com">